# Google Maps Api don't work when uploaded

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

My application does not work when I upload it to the play store. It works fine when installing it from android studio.

Is there something special that's need to be done with the api key?

Comment: check if you have used the debug keystore or release keystore?

Comment: Ok. Where can I check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows this would be the command to get SHA1 key

Open a terminal window.
​

- cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin
- Next we have to run the keytool.exe. Use the following line to get the Android SHA1 fingerprint.
- `​(PRODUCTION KEYSTORE)` keytool -exportcert -alias keystore -keystore "C:\Users\myusername\Documents\AndroidKeystore\androidkestore.jks" -list -v​
- ​`(DEBUG KEYSTORE:)​`
  keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android​

Note the third point where keystore for production is retrieved. You need to add this value into your developer console as shown below

[image]

Comment: I have checked and the SHA-1 is the debug key I am using so thats why its not working. I have tried to run the commands in you answer but does not work. Getting error **Alias keystore does not exist**

Comment: I mean you have to refer your keystore created for release purpose. And these steps is for Windows. Not sure about others

Comment: I have run this command: **keytool -list -keystore "C:\Users\Alexande
r\AndroidStudioProjects\StadsguidenKey.jks** And I am now using the correct SHA fingerprint but I cant get my map to show.

Comment: Hope you have added "  -list -v​"   after that command . Everything seems to be wright. Running out of clues

Comment: what if I generate a whole new key api key

Comment: So now I have created a new api key and it still does not work. Should I contact google at this point. The debugging is working but not the release fingerprint

Comment: I haven't used the **exportcert** Is this important.

Comment: The solution was that the xml release file didn't have the key only the debug. And that the fingerprint was wrong.

Comment: @alexandermogren Great! So u found the resolution

Comment: Yes and thanks to your answer the correct fingerprint is set

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Google Api Console -->> Select your Project --> Go to Credential --> Click on Api key you generated.

Here you can check the packageName And your SHA 1 check if eveythign is proper.(you have submitted correct SHA1)
And It should work.

Comment: I have checked my credentials and the package name is correct and there is a SHA-1 fingerprint and maybe its not correct but I generated the key with the instruction in the xml file when you create a map project.