# Google map not shown on devices that has android os version 6

Tags: android, google-maps

I am building application that contains map, and when test it on HTC device that has android os version 6, the map is not showing

can any one help me please?

Comment: Does your device has google play services installed?

Comment: yes it is installed, I can open google play and google maps and also can receive push notifications.

Comment: May we have a screenshot of the fragment with the map not showing? And pheraps a log of the activity, in verbose mode

Comment: Have you found a solution? If one answer helps you please consider to upvote or mark it

Answer (score 0):

Check if google play service is installed and also check SHA key is correct or not .Google maps are not device specific.

Answer (score 0):

> map is not showing

Reason can be one of the following:

- Rebug/Release keystore is wrongly updated in the project you created in developer console [SOReference Link for verifying SHA1 Key retrieved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740783/google-maps-api-dont-work-when-uploaded/37741343#37741343)
- Another issue can be Google playstore service is not the updated one. you can check using the following code

---

```
public static boolean isGooglePlayServiceAvailable(Activity context)
{
            GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(context, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                        .show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "This device is not supported. Google Play Services not installed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return true;
        }
        return true;
}
```

---

- Another reason can be of app having wrong `gcm_defaultSenderId` or wrong values of API KEY in the AndroidManifest

---

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="A****************************E" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you request the permission at run time?

From Android 6 users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

Check here how to request permission:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html