# Google map Release API Key not working

Tags: android, api, google-maps, api-key

Hi I am using google maps API, and I am having issues while creating a release APK. but Map is working fine in debug build. I created API key for release by following this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup). First I got SHA1 key by typing in terminal `keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name`. Using this key I created An API key from [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/?hl=fr) for android. Is there anything I am doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: What you gave in this `your_keystore_name` place.

Comment: You have to create a release build SHA1 key and add its print to the same api key in google developer console

Comment: Try to use key without fingerprint protection to narrow bug search

Comment: keytool -exportcert -alias MY_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore C:\Users\DEFAULT\keyStorePath\YOUR_KEY.jks -list -v

Comment: Check the accepted answer in the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740783/google-maps-api-dont-work-when-uploaded/37741343#37741343

Comment: Did you run the build/generate signed APK task and did you select the release keystore and alias?

Comment: @yugesh I gave the name of my keystore

Comment: @prabhatyadav thats what I did

Comment: @prabhatyadav I tried that method as well

Comment: @StanislavParkhomenko can you elaborate please

Comment: @dev.bmax yes I did

Comment: @BeardedBeast Okay. Map not Working means, its Show white Screen.

Comment: @BeardedBeast Fingerprint (SHA1 key) is used to allow use API key only in special package. So try create API key without that protection (without fingerprint) and use it.

Comment: @Yugesh yes thats what I meant

Comment: @StanislavParkhomenko Ok let me try

Comment: Double check that your com.google.android.geo.API_KEY meta-data tag is within the application tag of AndroidManifest.

Comment: Also, in the Google developer console in the credentials section you should be able to see both of your fingerprints (debug and release).

Comment: Sorry, It was a mistake. got the solution. I was adding API key into google_maps_api.xml inside src/debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml. Now I added it to src/release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml and it worked. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the solution. I was adding API key at wrong location. I added `release API key` inside `src/debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml` mistakenly. When I copied it to `src/release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml` it worked.