# After uprading to SupportMapFragment do you need a new google api map key?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, release

My release build doesn't recognize my v2 google map api key.  It works fine with a debug package name and corresponding debug key.  I know the key and package name have to match.  Is a new key required when upgrading to  SupportMapFragment ?

Comment: are you using release key for your release build

Comment: I got into a similar kind of issue and got it solved like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38439415/1769274).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no relation between key and SupportMapFragment.
Generate SHA for release key store and generate new API key from that.
Then use that new API key within the app.