# google map V2 not showing on android device debug mode

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I ported my android project to android studios a year or more ago. My google api keys were in the manifest.xml and now there is all this talk about google_map_api.xml

Steps I have taken:

1) I made a new SHA1 fingerprint via debug keystore and the keytool
2) Generated an API and used the package name and SHA1 fingerprint in google api consul
3) Taken the api key google generated and used it in my manifest.xml file as such:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_api_debug_key" />
```

4) in the resource xml file (strings)  I have

```
<string name="google_api_debug_key" translatable="false">MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY</string>
```

Should this not work? I don't have a google_map_api.xml file. I'm not an android developer, this app was written by someone else and I'm making changes to it.

Comment: If its written by some one else, do you have the credentials to that google developer credentials? Or did you created your own? Check this if accepted answer this helps.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740783/google-maps-api-dont-work-when-uploaded/37741343#37741343

Comment: no have my own credentials (own gmail account that generated the api key)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is dumb, but it turned out tha tI had not enabled the Google map api inside https://console.developers.google.com/apis/

burned.